# React onclick start animation + start another animation when first one is finished

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I am new to React and i would like to know what's the most preferable way to do the following:

1. click on button starts animation on box1
2. when box1 animation is finished box2 animation starts

Here are my components:

```
var StartButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button>Start</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Box1 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="box1"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Box2 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="box2"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
       <StartButton/>
        <Box1/>
        <Box2/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

I would appreciate a lot if someone would like to help me :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement jQuery promises.

https://api.jquery.com/promise/

On first promise solve start animate next container, on second promise solve start animation of the next one etc.

Comment: Go to that url of jquery API, on the bottom of the page you have demo that shows exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Animations**

Define `transition-delay` of `Box2` equal to `transition-duration` of `Box1`. This way when the transition of `Box1` completes, the `Box2` will start animating.

```
.box1 {
  /* other css */
  transition: all 10ms ease-in 0s;
}

.box2 {
  /* other css */
  transition: all 10ms ease-in 10ms;
}
```

**setTimeout + CSS Animations**

Add a `setTimeout` event with delay equal to the `transition-duration` of `Box1`. Start animation of `Box2` in the callback of `setTimeout` function.

Eg:

```
animate(box1Duration, box2Duration) {
    animate('Box1', box1Duration);
    setTimeout(function(){
      animate('Box2', box2Duration);
      }, box1Duration);
}
```

**Promises + CSS Animations**

Almost same implementation as the above, you will get a much more cleaner code. You will need to resolve the `Promise` n the callback function of `setTimeout`.  Also, you can directly use ES6 Promises. You need not include jQuery in React.

**Promises + requestAnimationFrame**

In case, your animations are quite complex, you could use RequestAnimationFrame on `Box1` returning a `Promise`. Whenever the animation completes, `resolve` the promise object. When the returned `Promise` resolves, you can start the animation for `Box2` again using the same `requestAnimationFrame` function.